# Is there a performance improvement using DATE over TIMESTAMP?

Tags: hadoop, hive

In Hive, are there any performance benefits of using DATE over TIMESTAMP?

Comment: Any difference in performance would not be noticeable for almost all operations.

Comment: BIGINT (epoch time) would be more performant than either. Plus, still depends on the storage format. ORC and Parquet obviously better than Text or JSON

Comment: In hive--- java.sql.Date (includes ms )and java.sql.Timestamp (include ns)...and both are wrapper around java.util.Date -which is a wrapper around primitive long number.so it is better to go with Bigint as in above comment..u may convert to the representation as needed

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html